CMakeList with non classical directory tree, for libraries building, installation and packaging
In order to simplify my projects management, I'm relying on a custom directories organisation, and a template of reusable configuration file:
<DevDir>
|-ModuleConfig.cmake.in (configuration file template)
|-CMakePackages (containing my project cmake configuration files)
|-SharedLibs (containing my shared libraries, referenced in my `PATH` environment variable)
|-<MyProject>
  |-src (containing .cpp files and CMakeLists.txt
  |-includes (containing .h files)
  |-libs (containing resulting lib binaries in the case of a static lib
    |-Debug
    |-Release
  |--build (to host my cmake build trees)
    |-Debug
    |-Release

Here is my CMakeLists.txt for msvc (the actual one is a bit more complex to manage various OS and compilers but the main ideas are there):
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
#TODO this line may be deprecated in the future
cmake_policy(VERSION ${CMAKE_VERSION})
set(CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_PREFER_CONFIG TRUE)

# Project paths
set(DEV_DIR_REL_PATH ../..)
set(DEV_DIR_PATH ${DEV_DIR_REL_PATH})
get_filename_component(DEV_DIR_PATH ${DEV_DIR_PATH} ABSOLUTE)

set(TARGET_NAME TestShared)
project(${TARGET_NAME} VERSION 1.0.0)

set(TARGET_PATH     ${DEV_DIR_PATH}/${TARGET_NAME})

# Build paths
set(LIB_PATH        ${TARGET_PATH}/libs)
set(BIN_PATH        ${TARGET_PATH}/bins)
set(SRC_PATH        ${TARGET_PATH}/src)
set(INCLUDE_PATH    ${TARGET_PATH}/includes)

# Installation paths
IF(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${TARGET_PATH} CACHE PATH "..." FORCE)
ENDIF()

# Installation relatives paths
set(INSTALL_LIB_PATH        libs)
set(INSTALL_BIN_PATH        bins)
set(INSTALL_INCLUDE_PATH    includes)

# CMake packages paths
set(CMAKEPACKAGE_PATH   ${DEV_DIR_PATH}/CMakePackages)
# Shared library installation path
set(SHAREDLIB_PATH  ${DEV_DIR_PATH}/SharedLibs)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKEPACKAGE_PATH})
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${SHAREDLIB_PATH})

# Configuration
set(CONFIG "Release" CACHE STRING "Config type")
set(CONFIGTYPE "Release" CACHE STRING "Config type")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE ${CONFIGTYPE})

# Target sources
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS_CPP ${SRC_PATH}/*.cpp)
LIST(APPEND SRCS ${SRCS_CPP})

# Target creation
add_library(${TARGET_NAME} SHARED)
target_sources(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE ${SRCS})
set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${TARGET_NAME}_${CONFIG})

# Import/export symbols
include(GenerateExportHeader)
generate_export_header(${TARGET_NAME})
string(TOLOWER ${TARGET_NAME} LOWER_TARGET_NAME)
if (EXISTS "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${LOWER_TARGET_NAME}_export.h")
    file(RENAME "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${LOWER_TARGET_NAME}_export.h" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}_export.h")
endif()
file(COPY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}_export.h DESTINATION "${INCLUDE_PATH}/${TARGET_NAME}")
string(TOUPPER ${TARGET_NAME} UPPER_TARGET_NAME)

set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED false)

# Removing CMake default compilation flags
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

# Langage
set(Standard cxx_std_14)
target_compile_features(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC ${Standard})
set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# Position Independent Code
set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

# Compiler options

# Compiler option that do not depend on configuration

include(CheckIPOSupported)
check_ipo_supported(RESULT IPO_SUPPORTED)
if(IPO_SUPPORTED)
    set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE)
endif()
set(MY_MSVC_OPTION  /LD /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /MP /Zc:__cplusplus /Zc:preprocessor /permissive-)
set(MY_WARNING_FLAGS /W4)
set(MY_CONFIG_FLAGS /MD /Ob2 /DNDEBUG /O2)
set(MY_COMPIL_FLAGS ${MY_MSVC_OPTION} ${MY_CONFIG_FLAGS} ${MY_WARNING_FLAGS})
target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE ${MY_COMPIL_FLAGS})
target_compile_definitions(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE NOMINMAX)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

# includes directories
target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC
$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${INCLUDE_PATH}>
$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${INCLUDE_PATH}>
)
target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE
$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${SRC_PATH}/${TARGET_NAME}>
)

# setting dependencies
set(MY_REQUIRED_DEPENDENCIES)
find_package(<LibName> REQUIRED)
list(APPEND MY_REQUIRED_DEPENDENCIES <LibName>)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} <PUBLIC|PRIVATE|INTERFACE> <LibName>::<LibName>)
configure_file(${DEV_DIR_REL_PATH}/ModuleConfig.cmake.in ${TARGET_NAME}Config.cmake @ONLY)
unset(MY_REQUIRED_DEPENDENCIES)

# Target output path
set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${LIB_PATH}/${CONFIG})
set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${LIB_PATH}/${CONFIG})

# Installation
install (
TARGETS ${TARGET_NAME}
EXPORT ${TARGET_NAME}Targets
LIBRARY DESTINATION ${INSTALL_LIB_PATH}/${CONFIG}
ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${INSTALL_LIB_PATH}/${CONFIG}
RUNTIME DESTINATION ${SHAREDLIB_PATH}
PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${INSTALL_INCLUDE_PATH}
)
install (
EXPORT ${TARGET_NAME}Targets
NAMESPACE ${TARGET_NAME}::
DESTINATION ${CMAKEPACKAGE_PATH}
)
# Install the ${TARGET_NAME}Config.cmake
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}Config.cmake"
DESTINATION ${CMAKEPACKAGE_PATH}
)

The configuration file template is:
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
foreach(_lib_ IN ITEMS @MY_REQUIRED_DEPENDENCIES@)
    find_dependency(${_lib_} REQUIRED)
endforeach()

# include the generated target file
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/@TARGET_NAME@Targets.cmake")

My headers and binaries are not moved during installation (binaries are built at their final location).
I see several issues, noticeably:

not fully relocatable, especially in the prospect of using CPack
too simple configuration template: I've got some dependency that need special logic before calling find_package for instance setting a different mode or a different search path according to the compiler and/or os (for instance, I may have two installations of the library, one for gcc, one for msvc).
outdated, it seems that in recent cmake version, headers should be manipulated through a FILE_SET
no version handling
configuration limited to debug or release, I'd like to manage more (for instance gcc_debug, msvc_release,...) and that a find_package on my library get the right configuration
possibly other issues...

I'd appreciate advice to improve/fix this CMakeLists.txt and the configuration template.
I know I'm also missing a coverage mode and enabling CTest, but I'm keeping it for later in order to limit the "problem" size.
